# The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'. while using list

Tags: json, flutter, fetch

This is my code:

```
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
          }
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? new ItemList(
                  list: snapshot.data,
                )
              : new Center(
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
        },
      ),
```

I get error in "list: snapshot.data,"
the error is
"The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'."

Please help me with the code, i am using the latest version of flutter.
Thank you...........

Comment: You can review [**Null Safety**](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) in dart, to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have problem with null safety

```
list: snapshot.data!,
```

this will fix your problem

Comment: yes it fixed, thanks a lot